# Search Yelp with tab in Chrome in locations other than San Francisco

Tags: google-chrome, yelp.com

If you press tab to search Yelp in Chrome, it will complete to:

http://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=things&src=opensearch

which searches San Francisco. This is not very useful to people living outside of San Francisco. How can I convince it to search a different location(or "Current Location", even if geoip based)?

Answer (score 1):

A fresh tab in Chrome for me completes to `http://www.yelp.com/richmond`

That happens even in an Incognito window. It could be you have something blocked at the browser level.

Additionally, you can choose locations like so:

`http://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=things&find_loc=Hoboken%2C+NJ`

Comment: This is referring to the address-bar search (type `ye` and press `tab`) - opening the web page in a tab does redirect to `/nyc` for me.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you *could* just type a new location in the "Near" box.

If you're looking for a URL parameter, use "find_loc". Example:

```
http://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=things&find_loc=Washington,+DC
```

That will [search for things in and near Washington, DC](http://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=things&find_loc=Washington,+DC).